# What races participated in the war of the ancients?

Tags: warcraft

In the War of the Ancients, what races participated in holding back the legion?

I know in the books it involved dragons, elves and a few time travelers. However at the time the world was filled with other races.

One of the comics the Pandaren had sent something to Queen Azshara, so they were around.  There were also earthen and iron vrykul in the world maintaining the titan areas.    What about the insect races?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Earthen, Tauren, Furbolg, and other races participated in the War of the Ancients.

The Earthen under Dungard Ironcutter,

> More astounding, he was made of stone, not flesh.  ...  "Dungard
>   Ironcutter, speaking for the clans of the Earthen" was all he said,
>   dwarves not much on conversation.
>   *The Earthen*. Malfurion made certain to remember the last. "Dwarf" was a night elven word, a derogatory one at that.
>
> The Tauren tribes united behind Huln Highmountain, Above the harsh,
>   wrinkled brow a pair of treacherous-looking horns thrust ahead of the
>   muzzle. A tauren... ... "Huln who speaks for all the tribes gathered."

the Furbolg,

> The creature lumbered forward. It resembled a bear, yet moved more
>   like a man. In some ways it reminded Malfurion of the twin gods, Ursoc
>   and Ursol, but it was clearly a primitive creature. It wore a pale,
>   brown loincloth and a necklace made of claws. The three-toed beastman
>   raised a club in one hand. The other four-fingered paw formed a fist.
>   The creature roared again, its tone slightly different from the first
>   time. "The furbolg Unng Ak says that he speaks for the packs," Rhonin
>   translated readily.

and [one](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Broxigar) orc 
[all took part in the War of the Ancients in the timeline altered by Rhonin and company.](https://books.google.com/books?id=qYZD0x3T_dwC&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=tauren+war+of+the+ancients&source=bl&ots=eTRO8e3Z7H&sig=dW_jt6YkCrrFDlmATUFtvcDTIWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1hMiWpoXQAhWIjFQKHRpmBgo4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=tauren%20war%20of%20the%20ancients&f=false)
As the tauren did not take place in the War of the Ancients in the unaltered timeline and Huln Highmountain currently exists in the WoW timeline, it can be concluded that this is canon.

In addition, numerous unnamed races were also present.

> There were others behind them, but they did not choose at this time to
>   step forth.

From this point, it's easier to define who *didn't* join in the war.

Pandaria, with the Pandarens, Mogu, and Mantids, was separated from the main landmass and surrounded by mists due to the actions of Emperor Shaohao, shortly after the beginning of the War.

> At the dusk of the final day, the sky was bathed in green fire, and
>   the very ground trembled in terror. But the Emperor was not afraid.
>   His mind was clear of any doubt or despair. He feasted and he sang as
>   the sky tore open. ... And as the Emperor's robes fluttered empty to
>   the ground, the land became enveloped in impenetrable mists, hidden
>   away from the rest of the world.
>   [The Emperor's Burden, part 8](http://wow.gamepedia.com/The_Emperor%27s_Burden_-_Part_8)

The Tauren trapped in Pandaria were enslaved by the Mogu, under Qiang the Merciless, and were forcibly changed into the Yaungol of today. (Chronicles I)

The Nerubians were isolated in Northrend, where they took over Tol'vir settlements. [Corroborated by Zarhym on the forums.](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1008430853)

The Qiraji were gathering forces within Ahn'Qiraj, where they worked to turn C'thun's prison into a seat of power.

> The Old God would create avatars from the Silithid in its own image.
>   These avatars were to be known as Qiraji. Sentient and with purpose,
>   the Qiraji would name their creator: C'Thun was born... For many
>   thousands of years the Qiraji worked feverishly to build a force
>   capable of laying waste to the world that would betray their god. The
>   great fortress city of Ahn'Qiraj was created to house their growing
>   armies and prepare for the coming of C'Thun.
>   [The Prophecy of C'thun, as told by Geologist Larksbane](http://wow.gamepedia.com/The_Prophecy_of_C%27Thun)

The Vrykul in Northrend were in a hibernation initiated by Loken.

> Data suggests that impetus for global combat originated with prime
>   designate Loken who neutralized all remaining Aesir and Vanir
>   affecting termination of conflict. Prime designate Loken then
>   initiated stasis of several seed races including Earthen, Giants and
>   Vrykul at designated holding facilities.
>   [The Tribunal of Ages](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Tribunal_of_Ages#Quotes)

Vrykul south of Northrend did not take part in the War of the Ancients, largely being concentrated in Tirisfal, where they followed Tyr and guard his tomb to this day. (Chronicles I)

Comment: Sounds right except for Tol'vir... thought they were just isolated to Uldum by the Titans for everything before Cataclysm.

Comment: @Radhil The Nerubians took over their Northrend settlements, thus explaining why the Nerubians have the same architecture.

Comment: Huh.  Didn't think the buildings were that unique (Ahn'Qiraj wasn't that different) but simple Googling backs you up.  I can't keep up with the retcons anymore, apparently.

Comment: @Radhil You and me both.